# Increase Python code speed

Tags: python, performance

Does anyone have a clue how to increase the speed of this part of python code?
It was designed to deal with small files (with just a few lines, and for this is very fast) but i want to run it with big files (with ~50Gb, and millions of lines).

The main goal of this code is to get stings from a file (.txt) and search for these in a input file printing the the number of times that these occurred in the output file.

Here is the code: `infile`, `seqList` and `out` are determined by the optparse as Options in the beginning of the code (not shown)

```
def novo (infile, seqList, out) :
    uDic = dict()
    rDic = dict()
    nmDic = dict()

    with open(infile, 'r') as infile, open(seqList, 'r') as RADlist :
        samples = [line.strip() for line in RADlist]
        lines = [line.strip() for line in infile]

    #Create dictionaires with all the samples
        for i in samples:
            uDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
            rDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
            nmDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0

        for k in lines:
            l1 = k.split("\t")
            l2 = l1[0].split(";")
            l3 = l2[0].replace(">","")
            if len(l1)<2:
                continue
            if l1[4] == "U":
                for k in uDic.keys():
                    if k == l3:
                        uDic[k] += 1

            if l1[4] == "R":
                for j in rDic.keys():
                    if j == l3:
                        rDic[j] += 1

            if l1[4] == "NM":
                for h in nmDic.keys():
                    if h == l3:
                        nmDic[h] += 1

    f = open(out, "w")
    f.write("Sample"+"\t"+"R"+"\t"+"U"+"\t"+"NM"+"\t"+"TOTAL"+"\t"+"%R"+"\t"+"%U"+"\t"+"%NM"+"\n")
    for i in samples:
        U = int()
        R = int()
        NM = int ()
        for k, j in uDic.items():
            if k == i:
                U = j
        for o, p in rDic.items():
            if o == i:
                R = p
        for y,u in nmDic.items():
            if y == i:
                NM = u
        TOTAL = int(U + R + NM)
        try:
         f.write(i+"\t"+str(R)+"\t"+str(U)+"\t"+str(NM)+"\t"+str(TOTAL)+"\t"+str(float(R) / TOTAL)+"\t"+str(float(U) / TOTAL)+"\t"+str(float(NM) / TOTAL$
        except:
         continue

    f.close()
```

Comment: For a dataset of N size, how long does the run take? What duration are you targeting/expecting? Where do you think specific inefficiencies lie in this code? Without more details, this cannot be answered effectively.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

With processing 50 GB files, the question is not how to make it faster, but how to make it runnable
at all.

The main problem is, you will run out of memory and shall modify the code to be processing the files
without having all the files in memory, but rather having in memory onle a line, which is needed.

Following code from your question is reading all the lines form two files:

```
with open(infile, 'r') as infile, open(seqList, 'r') as RADlist :
    samples = [line.strip() for line in RADlist]
    lines = [line.strip() for line in infile]
# at this moment you are likely to run out of memory already

#Create dictionaires with all the samples
for i in samples:
    uDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
    rDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
    nmDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0

#similar loop over `lines` comes later on
```

You shall defer reading the lines till the latest possible moment like this:

```
#Create dictionaires with all the samples
with open(seqList, 'r') as RADlist:
    for samplelines in RADlist:
        sample = sampleline.strip()
        for i in samples:
            uDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
            rDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
            nmDic[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
```

Note: did you want to use `line.strip()` or `line.split()`?

This way, you do not have to keep all the content in memory.

There are many more options for optimization, but this one will let you to take off and run.

Answer (score 1):

It would make it much easier if you provided some sample inputs. Because you haven't I haven't tested this, but the idea is simple - iterate through each file only once, using iterators rather than reading the whole file into memory. Use the efficient `collections.Counter` object to handle the counting and minimise inner looping:

```
def novo (infile, seqList, out):
    from collections import Counter
    import csv


    # Count
    counts = Counter()
    with open(infile, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            l1 = line.strip().split("\t")
            l2 = l1[0].split(";")
            l3 = l2[0].replace(">","")
            if len(l1)<2:
                continue
            counts[(l1[4], l3)] += 1


    # Produce output
    types = ['R', 'U', 'NM']
    with open(seqList, 'r') as RADlist, open(out, 'w') as outfile:
        f = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
        f.writerow(types + ['TOTAL'] + ['%' + t for t in types])
        for sample in RADlist:
            sample = sample.strip()
            countrow = [counts((t, sample)) for t in types]
            total = sum(countrow)
            f.writerow([sample] + countrow + [total] + [c/total for c in countrow])

        samples = [line.strip() for line in RADlist]
        lines = [line.strip() for line in infile]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your script into functions (it makes profiling easier), and then see what it does when you code profile it : I suggest using runsnake : [runsnakerun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/)

Comment: This is more of a comment, since the "question" is how to increase the speed and not how to search for bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing your loops with list & dictionary comprehensions:

For example, instead of

```
for i in samples:
   uDict[i.replace(" ","")] = 0
```

Try:

```
udict = {i.replace(" ",""):0 for i in samples}
```

and similarly for the other dicts

I don't really follow what's going on in your "for k in lines" loop, but you only need l3 (and l2) when you have certain values for l1[4]. Why not check for those values before splitting and replacing?

Lastly, instead of looping through all the keys of a dict to see if a given element is in that dict, try:

```
if x in myDict:
  myDict[x] = ....
```

for example:

```
for k in uDic.keys():
    if k == l3:
       uDic[k] += 1
```

can be replaced with:

```
if l3 in uDic:
  uDic[l3] += 1
```

Other than that, try profiling.

Answer (score 0):

1)Look into profilers and adjust the code that is taking the most time.

2)You could try optimizing some methods with Cython - use data from profiler to modify correct thing

3)It looks like you can use a counter instead of a dict for the output file, and a set for the input file -look into them.

```
set = set()
from Collections import Counter
counter = Counter() # Essentially a modified dict, that is optimized for counting... 
                    # like counting occurences of strings in a text file
```

4) If you are reading 50GB of memory you won't be able to store it all in RAM (I'm assuming who knows what kind of computer you have), so generators should save your memory and time.

```
#change list comprehension to generators
samples = (line.strip() for line in RADlist) 
lines = (line.strip() for line in infile)
```